# Skyrim: Quest not showing in game log

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Quest "Forbidden Legend" (id: dungauldursonqst) not showing in gamelog, but active...
I'm print command in console :

```
sqv dungauldursonqst
.....
.....
Enabled? Yes
State: Running
Current stage : 32
Priority: 50
```

I can make quest stages , but the quest not showing in log... How do I fix it ?

Comment: How'd you activate it in the first place?

Comment: Probably - in Folgunthur by reading the journal of Daynas Valen in the camp outside the cave.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [UESP article on Forbidden Legend](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend)., there are actually three ways to activate the quest without it showing on your quest log:

- Defeat Sigdis in Geirmund's Hall
- Defeat Jyrik in Saarthal
- Defeat Mikrul in Folgunthur

If you simply killed the quest NPC and failed to read the [writ of sealing](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Writ_of_Sealing_(Sigdis)), the quest will be ACTIVE but you will not have a quest log.

In order to get the quest to show up, the trigger will be **reading** one of the related quest item.

Answer (score -1):

Try a hard reset it always work for me when i have problems

Comment: What do you mean by hard reset?

Comment: you should provide more info as what "hard reset" means and how to do it.